# How to remove first array values PHP

Tags: php, csv

I tried to export csv files so I got an array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Name
    [1] => Emp Code
    [2] => Designation
    [3] => Basic
    [4] => DA
    [5] => HRA
    [6] => CCA
    [7] => Conveyance
    [8] => Others
    [9] => Mgt Contr PF
    [10] => PL Encashment
    [11] => Income Tax
    [12] => Prof Tax
    [13] => Welfare Fund
)
Array
(
    [0] => Li
    [1] => 60
    [2] => Web Designer
    [3] => 14400
    [4] => 9600
    [5] => 4800
    [6] => 4800
    [7] => 1600
    [8] => 12800
    [9] => 800
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 0
    [12] => 0
    [13] => 20
)
```

Here first array values are the csv file column name, so I don't want to save them in database.

Here is my code

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                            $num = count($data);

                            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                                $importData_arr[$i][] = $data[$c];
                            }
                            $i++;
                        }
                          fclose($file);
                            $skip = 0;
                             foreach($importData_arr as $data){
                                 echo '<pre>';print_r($data);
                             }
        }
```

How can I remove column name from array. Please help me

Comment: you can simply use `unset` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php such as `unset($array[0])`

Comment: you can also try array_shift() https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_shift.asp

Comment: I don't understand you, but if you would like to combine the first array values as a key and the second array values as a value in one array you can use [array_combine] https://www.php.net/array_combine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip the first row by reading it prior to the loop. You can also massively simplify your code:

```
fgets($file);
while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $importData_arr[] = $data;                        
}
fclose($file);
$skip = 0;
foreach($importData_arr as $data){
    echo '<pre>';print_r($data);
}
```

Comment: I totally missed that i can simplify OP's code itself to make it simple and get desired output. good catch.+1

Answer (score 0):

use [unset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) function:

```
unset($importData_arr[0]);
```